# Is there any research on the action of a subgroup on the whole finite group by conjugation?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I want to know whether there are any research on the orbits of the action of a **subgroup** by **conjugation** on the whole group, when the group is finite. (Especially whole symmetric group.)

I'm especially interested in calculating subclass algebra that was introduced by Eugene Wigner in the paper "Restriction of irreducible representations of groups to a subgroup" (1971).

For a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H$ acts on $G$ by conjugation and $G$ is partitioned into the orbits $\{ B_{i} \}$.

For a group algebra $k[G]$ over a field $k$, the subclass algebra is defined to be the subspace (as a vector space) of $k[G]$ spanned by $\sum_{g \in B_{i}}g$ as the basis. Then it is known to be an algebra. The study of this algebra gives us information on the restrictions of representations of $G$ to $H$.

The problem is that I couldn't find any paper which has computed an example of subclass algebras for $G=S_{n}$ for a non-trivial proper subgroup of $G$ yet.

(Maybe except for the papers of Stephen Humphries on the commutative Schur rings but I haven't checked that the Schur ring is a subclass algebra yet.)

So I'm trying to compute **any** example by myself. I hope to be able to compute as many subclass algebras (with respect to many subgroups) as possible to get many information on the representation of $S_{n}$.

Therefore I want to ask.

For the symmetric group $S_{n}$, are there any subgroups $H$ of $S_{n}$ such that there are theorems like

> For two elements $x,y$ of $S_{n}$, $x$ is conjugate of $y$ by an element of $H$ if and only if …. ?

I especially want to try the case when H is a maximal subgroup.

Any suggestion of related works (ex. chapters of the main references, fundamental result in this line for any pair of groups G, H) are welcome to me.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your first paragraph is very vague, and the answer is certainly "yes" -- there is a great deal of such research, of many different kinds. Your second paragraph seems like a good research question. I suggest you edit your question to focus on that paragraph. It would be even better if you could state clearly in exactly which contexts you want to compute this subclass algebra.  Best of all would be a well-defined question, which admits either a proof or counterexample.

Comment: One person who has considered such question is Harald Ellers